# Opposite function of push notification

Tags: android, function, mobile, iso

Push notification enable server side send data to client side without client request.

However, I want an opposite way.

I want the client side send data back to server by regular time, even thought client side doesn't activate the mobile app.

I searh this function for long time.  Is there any existing function can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Android Services for this. You can use AlarmManager system service to schedule your service to run at specific intervals. Check the tutorial below.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Hope this helps
-Raghu